# Custom function added to Drupal core removed by upgrade

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've recently upgraded a site to Drupal 7.59 with install profile:

Commerce Kickstart (commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.54)

Previously there was a function that had been added to the core which has now been removed because of the upgrade.  This shouldn't have been added to the core and I'm not sure why it was.  I've added this function back in and its not doing what it did previously so I'm not sure what other changes I would need to make to get it to work.

Here's the function which is found in `/profiles/commerce_kickstart/themes/commerce_kickstart_admin/template.php` -

```
function commerce_kickstart_admin_commerce_price_formatted_components($variables) {
// Add the CSS styling to the table.
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_price') . '/theme/commerce_price.theme.css');

// Build table rows out of the components.
$rows = array();

foreach ($variables['components'] as $name => $component) {
  $rows[] = array(
    'data' => array(
      array(
        'data' => $component['title'],
        'class' => array('component-title'),
      ),
      array(
        'data' => $component['formatted_price'],
        'class' => array('component-total'),
      ),
    ),
    'class' => array(drupal_html_class('component-type-' . $name)),
  );
}

if($variables['components']['discount']['price']['amount']){
  unset($rows[0]);
  unset($rows[2]);
}else{
  $rows = array_splice($rows, 2);
}

return theme('table', array('rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('commerce-price-formatted-components'))));
}
```

Can anyone give any pointers as to how to get this working?  It doesn't appear to even be getting invoked.

Additional info from the comments:

`it's a function in the profile?`
yes

`Was the function added afterwards (as in "Never hack core")?`
Yes, looks like it.

`Or was it removed by the maintainers?`
Doesn't look like this was ever part of any official release

`Do you use some version control system like Git?`
Yes.  This function was added on 14/05/2015 12:18 according to the repo.

`Have you checked the profile's release notes and issue queue?`
Had a look but don't see anything.

Comment: So it's not core, it's a function in the profile? Was the function added afterwards (as in "Never hack core")? Or was it removed by the maintainers? Do you use some version control system like Git? Have you checked the profile's release notes and issue queue? Do this and then come back to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the extra info!

Well, if this really was custom code than it should never have been added to the profile in the first place. Never ever add custom code to any core or contrib file. As it's going to be deleted as soon as you update. Like it has happened to you.

I guess the most important part of this custom function was `drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_price') . '/theme/commerce_price.theme.css');` and that this `commerce_price.theme.css` maybe also got deleted.

Apart from that it's hard to tell from far and I'm not an expert in the commerce module. So, what I would do now is to narrow down the issue systematically.

1. Restore your repo to a time in history before this module got updated and get the site running.
2. Find out what this code is doing exactly, what other functions or flows are involved. Maybe with the help of the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and the mighty `dpm()` function.
3. Try to rebuild the custom code from the profile in a custom module.
4. Then reset the repo to the current state and see if your custom module's code is still firing. If not, debug it to match the updated profile's code.

Apart from that, find the person who added the code and ask them why and what this code is doing. And tell them to never ever again hack core or contrib code :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I'll see what I can do with it, unfortunately the person who did this no longer with the company and there is nobody else I can ask :(